# Chapter 2 Theorem 6 Hoffman and Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

[image]

I can't understand from that Red part and what follows.

Basically how do we get that summation with $\gamma$ involving only $\alpha$ on the right side ?

Comment: becouse the sum belongs to $W_1$v and to $W_2$ thus it belongs to $W_1 \cap W_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sum z_r\gamma_r$ belongs to $W_1$ and $W_2$, then $\sum z_r\gamma_r$ belongs to $W_1\cap W_2$. Since $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k\}$ is a basis for $W_1\cap W_2$ and $\sum z_r\gamma_r\in W_1\cap W_2$, then we can write $\sum z_r\gamma_r$ as the following linear combination:
$$\sum z_r\gamma_r=\sum c_i\alpha_i$$
for some choice of scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_k$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @RuanCarlos If you're satisfied with the answer please accept it by clicking on the check-mark on the left of the answer